# Using For loops in Google Engine and output a chart or table of values

Tags: javascript

My problem is after using a for loop in Google Earth Engine how to output variables and create a chart using it. as an example I tried the following code to output a 
ee.reducer.cout() value assigned to c but instead of printing it within the loop. how do i output or return c values in to an array, so that I can call it for another code such as chart printing.

```
 for (var i = 0;i<series1.size().getInfo();i++){
 var l_masked = ee.Image(series1list.get(i));
 var cloud_mask = ee.Image(series2list.get(i));
 var cloud_cover = l_masked.updateMask(cloud_mask)
     .set('system:time_start', l_masked.get('system:time_start'));
  var c = cloud_cover.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: rm_sh
 });}
```

Comment: Add array before `for` loop like `var arr = [];` and after line `c = ...` push `c` to array like `arr.push(c);`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Karan. But in Google Earth Engine normal javascript methods aren't working. such as when creating a variable you have assign the variable to something. without assigning you cannot create a variable. eg:` var arr = []` will not create an array called arr. instead you have to create `var arr = ee.Array(something to assign to)`. And there is nothing to assign to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again Thank you Karan for your quick reply. I was able to finally run the code successfully.

```
 var arr1 = [];
 for (var i = 0;i<series1.size().getInfo();i++){
 var l_masked = ee.Image(series1list.get(i));
 var cloud_mask = ee.Image(series2list.get(i));
 var cloud_cover = l_masked.updateMask(cloud_mask)
 .set('system:time_start', l_masked.get('system:time_start'));
 Map.addLayer(cloud_cover,{min:0 , 
 max:32000},''+l_masked.getInfo().properties['system:index'])
 var c = cloud_cover.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.count(), geometry: rm_sh });
 arr1[i]=c;   
  }
  print(arr1);
```